# how to construct a dynamic query for a many to one relationship using the CriteriaBuilder of JPA 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, criteria, jpa-2.0

I stucked constructing a dynamic query using the CriteriaBuilder in JPA 2.0. My application is  Spring 3.0, Hibernate 3.6.0 + JPA 2.0  based. Actually I have two entities one is `taUser` and another one is `taContact`, in  my `taUser` class has one property ,that has many to one relationship with `taContact` my pojo  classes  are (sample example)

```
public class TaUser implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int userId;
    private TaContact taContact;
    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public TaContact getTaContact() {
        return taContact;
    }

    public void setTaContact(TaContact taContact) {
        this.taContact = taContact;
    }

    }


   public class TaContact implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int contactId;

    public int getContactId() {
        return this.contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(int contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }
   private int contactNumber;

    public int getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

   }
```

and my  orm .xml

```
<entity class="com.common.model.TaUser" name="TaUser">
        <table name="ta_user" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="userId">
                <column name="USER_ID" />
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <many-to-one name="taContact"
                target-entity="TaContact">
                <join-column name="Contact_id" />
            </many-to-one>
</attributes>
</entity>
```

How can I create constructing a dynamic query using criteria actually this is my jpql query I want to change it into constructing a dynamic query  using criterias.

```
String jpql = 
    "select * from Tauser user where user.userId = "1" and user.taContact.contactNumber="8971329902";
```

How can I check the second where condition?

> user.taContact.contactNumber="8971329902"

```
Root<T> rootEntity;
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = null;
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = this.getJpaTemplate()
                .getEntityManagerFactory();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManagerFactory
                .getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TaUser.class);
                rootEntity = criteriaQuery.from(TaUser.class);
                criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEntity.get("userId"),
                "1"));
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEntity.get("taContact.contactNumber"),
        "8971329902")); --- here  i m getting error 
    at 

org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:189)
    at com.evolvus.core.common.dao.CommonDao.findByCriteria(CommonDao.java:155)
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are many wey to use that Dynamic query in a JPA EntityManagerFactory.

1. If you use JPA <s>Entity class and Use Hibernate 3 JPA</s> annotations then you can define the query using the `@NamedQuery` Annotation.
2. You can use `javax.persistence.Query` to create a Dynamic query.

   ```
   Query q1=em.createQuery("SELECT TaUser AS tu WHERE tu.userId = :USERID");
   //em is entityManager object
   q1.setInteger("USERID",34);
   //here 34 is the dynamic value or if there is any relationship with
   // another entity then set the object reference of the other entity.
   q1.getResultList(); //return list of data.
   ```
3. You can use the Hibernate Criteria API.

But the thing is that if u want to create criteria you need to initialize the session object. So, to get session object use your entity manager object.

Comment: please: if English is not your native language, that's OK. But try not to make everything worse by writing LOL-speak like 'u' instead of 'you'. Also, try not to misspell classes, packages and technologies you refer to. Your post is difficult enough to read as it is.

Comment: I tried to fix your post, but even so, your answer is irrelevant, as the question is about the JPA 2 Criteria API, not the Hibernate Criteria API.

Comment: Hi Sean Patrick Floyd, your second comment  is  right. Than  why cant you  give me any suggestion ?

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd :In my answar i used JPA 2 Criteria API thats why am using this javax.persistence.Query not org.hibernate.Criteria,And thanks for you tips..:)

Comment: The question was about "using the CriteriaBuilder of JPA 2.0", why do you propose other ways of querying?

Answer (score 14):

I guess this is the way to do it:

```
public TaUser getUserByIdAndContactNumber(
    final long userId,
    final long contactNumber){

    final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<TaUser> query = cb.createQuery(TaUser.class);
    final Root<TaUser> root = query.from(TaUser.class);
    query
        .where(cb.and(
            cb.equal(root.get("userId"), userId),
            cb.equal(root.get("taContact").get("contactNumber"), contactNumber)
        ));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

BTW, 8971329902 is way to large for an `int` field. Set the field type to `long`.